# Проблема с NavBar в Yii2 Advanced - доставляется /frontend/web при urlManager

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте. Настроил `urlManager` и подключил .htaccess. Но дело в том, что при клике на пункте меню я получаю ссылку вида:

```
/frontend/web/site/about
```

вместо

```
/site/about
```

Меню формируется с помощью NavBar. Использую Yii2 Advanced.
Пример заполнения ячеек:

```
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Главная', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ['label' => 'О нас', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
    ['label' => 'Обратная связь', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
];
```

UrlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '<controller>'              => '<controller>/index',
    ],
],
```

Возможно ли при формировании получать ссылку вида `/site/about`.
Помнится, на другом проекте настраивал - проблем не было с NavBar.

Comment: Упоминаете urlManager, но его не показываете...

Comment: @noxom, точно, забыл, спасибо. Добавил их в пост.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в config:

```
...
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => '',
        ],
...
```